# What will happen if i download 100 MB data in onReceive() method of Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: android, exception, broadcastreceiver

I have a receiver which catches an alarm/system broadcasts and then it has to get the `heavy data` from the `server` and then send a notification. The data which i am getting from server is more than 100 MB. what happens when i try to download, it will give any errors (or) if i increase the data size to more than 200 MB, then it will give any exception ?

if it giving any error how to override those errors and able to download the data from server ?

Comment: `BroadcastReceiver`s aren't meant to live very long, and your download would most likely fail part-way through. Start an `IntentService` in `onReceive()` to handle the download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `BroadcastReceiver` hasn't finished executing within 10 seconds (In your case, it hasn't downloaded the whole 100MB), it will trigger ANR (Application not responding) http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Consider using `IntentService` within your `BroadcastReceiver` to handle the download process.